# Neural Network Learner Orange ML

Tags: python, machine-learning, orange

I am having issues getting this particular library to work. 
I've tried dir(orange) and can't seem to find anything about neural networks in it.

The documentation shows it here:

http://docs.orange.biolab.si/reference/rst/Orange.classification.neural.html

however whenver I try orange.NeuralNetworkLearner(...) it says that the method doesn't exist. (I also tried small n for neural).

Is this feature not implemented or am I just confused?

Comment: `Orange.classification.neural.NeuralNetworkLearner` is the full path. So you might need to call it accordingly.

Comment: ok, that is making more sense, I was trying to follow convention from the SImpleCV repo, and use the same format as orange.TreeLearner, for example, looks like I'll need to point to Orange. thank you for the suggestion, im still not sure what the difference between orange and Orange is with this lib